# Красивый вывод из списка в одну строку

Tags: python, list, telebot

Требуется в одном сообщении месенджера красиво разместить информацию (список каналов) в виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но лучшее что я придумал, это вывод каждого канала в одном сообщении в цикле.
Скорее всего решение состоит в использовании lambda выражении, но я не уверен.

Код который выводит сообщения в цикле:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['my_channels'])
def my_channels(message):
    channels = users_db.get_channels(message.chat.id)
    for channel in channels:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{channel[0]}. {channel[1]}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так не работает ?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['my_channels'])
def my_channels(message):
    channels = users_db.get_channels(message.chat.id)
    text = '\n'.join(f'{chn[0]}. {chn[1]}' for chn in channels)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```